# Access atomic vectors shown by Filter(is.atomic, eq) in R

Tags: r, functional-programming

```
Filter(is.atomic, something)
```

returns atomic vectors.

**1. Weather -example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8743556/how-to-address-data-in-a-hierarchical-data-structure-in-r)**

```
> Filter(is.atomic, study)
$region
[1] "Hamburg" "Bremen"
```

**2. mosaic-plot-as-tree-plot -example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4996424/representing-a-mosaic-plot-as-a-tree-plot)**

```
> Map(function(x) Filter(is.atomic, x), ls())
$g
[1] "g"

$lookup
[1] "lookup"

$req.data
[1] "req.data"

$tmp
[1] "tmp"

$tmp1
[1] "tmp1"
```

Look their positions can be arbitrary, I may have faintest clue of their data-structure so cannot use `var$some$...$vector`. I feel the need of `?Position`. Use your imagination, the examples are not exclusive. How can I access their atomic vectors?

Comment: That's not what downvotes are for (reciprocal attacks). I didn't downvote, but I can see why someone might - your question isn't very clear. Do you just want to access vectors in the objects you link to? Do you want to traverse an arbitrary list and return atomic vectors? How about you give an explicit example **with** the expected output so it is very clear what you want.

Comment: +1 for Gavin's answer, but I think it is reasonable to ask "why the downvote?" in a more neutral tone -- for purposes of education ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To flatten a list so you can access the atomic vectors, you can use following function:

```
flatten.list <- function(x){
  y <- list()
  while(is.list(x)){
    id <- sapply(x,is.atomic)
    y <- c(y,x[id])
    x <- unlist(x[!id],recursive=FALSE)
  }
  y
}
```

This function maintains names of the elements. Usage, using the list x from Vincent's answer :

```
x <- list(
   list(1:3, 4:6),
   7:8,
   list( list( list(9:11, 12:15), 16:20 ), 21:24 )
)
```

then:

```
> flatten.list(x)
[[1]]
[1] 7 8

[[2]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[3]]
[1] 4 5 6

[[4]]
[1] 21 22 23 24

...
```

To recursively do an action on all atomic elements in a list, use `rapply()` (which is what Vincent handcoded basically).

```
> rapply(x,sum)
[1]  6 15 15 30 54 90 90

> rapply(x,sum,how='list')
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 6

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 15


[[2]]
[1] 15

...
```

See also `?rapply`

PS : Your code `Map(function(x) Filter(is.atomic, x), ls())` doesn't make sense. `ls()` returns a character vector, so every element of that character vector will be returned as part of the list. This doesn't tell you anything at all.

Next to that, `Filter()` doesn't do what you believe it does. Taking the example list `x`,  from the answer of Vincent, accessing only the atomic parts of it is pretty easy. `Filter()` only returns the second element. That's the only atomic element. `Filter(is.atomic, x)` is 100% equivalent to:

```
ind <- sapply(x, is.atomic)
x[ind]
```

Comment: ...is there some function that returns itself `I:=(lambda x. x)`? I mean `rapply(x, returnTheAtomicVectorsAsTheyAre)`? `dput(rapply(x, unlist))` returns `1:24`, not keeping the structure.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very unclear, to say the least: an example of the input data you have and the desired output would help...

Since you suggest that we "use our imagination", I assume that you have a hierarchical data structure, i.e., a list of lists of...of lists, whose depth is unknown. For instance,

```
x <- list(
  list(1:3, 4:6),
  7:8,
  list( list( list(9:11, 12:15), 16:20 ), 21:24 )
)
```

The leaves are vectors, and you want to do "something" with those vectors.

For instance, you may want to concatenate them into a single vector: that is what the `unlist` function does.

```
unlist(x)
```

You could also want all the leaves, in a list, i.e., a list of vectors.
You can easily write a (recursive) function that explores the data structure and progressively builds that list, as follows.

```
leaves <- function(u) {
  if( is.atomic(u) ) { return( list(u) ) }
  result <- list()
  for(e in u) {
    result <- append( result, leaves(e) )
  }
  return(result)
}
leaves(x)
```

You could also want to apply a function to all the leaves, while preserving the structure of the data.

```
happly <- function(u, f, ...) {
  if(is.atomic(u)) { return(f(u,...)) }
  result <- lapply(u, function(v) NULL) # List of NULLs, with the same names
  for(i in seq_along(u)) {
    result[[i]] <- happly( u[[i]], f, ... )
  }
  return( result )
}
happly(x, range) # Apply the "range" function to all the leaves
```

Answer (score 1):

`Filter` will return a list. The functions `lapply` and `sapply` are typically used to process individual elements of a list object. If you instead want to access them by number using "[" or "[[" then you can determine the range of acceptable numbers with `length(object)`. So `object[[length(object)]]` would get you the last element (as would ( `tail(object, 1)` ).